# Which data structure should I choose for Orthogonal Range Searching?

Tags: data-structures, r-tree, range-tree

I need to solve a neighbor search problem, that is, for every given element, find all neighbor elements within a fixed distance.

I just learnt the data structure `range tree`, it seems to be able to solve this problem in O(N*(log(N)^(d-1))) complexity where d is dim of space.

I know nothing about `R-tree`, but just saw this from [wikipedia](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/R-tree):

> A common real-world usage for an R-tree might be to .... then find answers quickly to queries such as "Find all museums
>   within 2 km of my current location",

which seems exactly the problem I want to solve.

So should I learn and use this data structure？

Comment: Yes, learn everything. The R* tree is really good.

Comment: Could you please explain some advantages R* tree have over using range tree?

Comment: i don't know the range tree